# ASP.NET Add Command Argument to Button in Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to grab an argument added to an asp:button in code behind, but getting error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs'

This button is part of a normal form, not a gridview, etc..

What might I be doing wrong? Regards.

```
<form><asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CommandArgument="" /></form>

Imports System.Web

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim String AS String = "MyValue"
    btnPrint.CommandArgument = String

End Sub    

Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click


     Dim ID as String = e.CommandArgument.toString

     'Have also tried
      'Dim btn As Button = sender
      'Dim ID As String = btn.CommandArgument

      Response.Redirect("Print.aspx?tid=" & ID)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update `btnPrint_Click` to handle the [`Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) event instead of "Click":

```
Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Command
```

Answer (score 0):

My ASP button click events look like this:

```
Private Sub SearchASPxButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchASPxButton.Click
```

Notice the second parameter is of type System.EventArgs.  Did you change the type of the automatically generated click event?  Or did you create this manually yourself?

Comment: Is this 'Handles SearchASPXButton.Click' Correct? I am getting error 'requires WithEvents variable'

Comment: Thats the name on my control, not yours. Looks like you wanted the Command event anyways, not the click event.